# Trigger and update to a row in SQL Server after it's been updated

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

Is this the best way to keep a simple track of changes to a database row:

```
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[trg_121s] 
ON  [dbo].[121s]
  AFTER UPDATE
AS 
BEGIN
-- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
-- interfering with SELECT statements.
SET NOCOUNT ON;

-- Insert statements for trigger here

update dbo.[121s]
set modified=getdate()
where id in 
(select distinct ID from Inserted)

END
```

So any update to a row in [121s] will result in the **modified** column being updated.

It works, but I'm not sure if it's the best way to achieve this.

I'm a litle confused over this line:

```
(select distinct ID from Inserted)
```

...and how it knows it's getting the correct row ID.

Thanks for any confirmation/clarification,

Mark

Comment: Using `GetDate()` within a query is chasing a moving target, impacts performance, and may produce curious results, e.g. as the date changes.  It is almost always a better idea to capture the current date/time in a variable and then use that value as needed.  This is more important across multiple statements as in a stored procedure.  The most common reason to use `GetDate()` multiple times is when capturing the start and end times for a long running operation.

Comment: @HABO unless it is absolutely critical that all of the rows are marked with the exact same update timestamp, I don't think there's much of a concern in this case.

Comment: I do not know for sure, but I think in a statement the getdate() will return the same date/time for every row.

Comment: @DumitrescuBogdan I am fairly certain there are cases where that isn't true, and it's re-evaluated per-row, but I will confess that I haven't tested if this is one of them.

Comment: @AaronBertrand don't understand me wrong, whenever I write an sp I always start by defining some constants(like time). But I am yet to see inside a select/update/insert, different dates from getdate(). As I said, i do not know it for sure. I will investigate.

Comment: @DumitrescuBogdan for simple cases I believe you are correct, but for some more complex cases see https://sqlblog.org/blogs/andrew_kelly/archive/2008/02/27/when-getdate-is-not-a-constant.aspx and https://sqlblog.org/blogs/andrew_kelly/archive/2008/03/01/when-a-function-is-indeed-a-constant.aspx

Comment: @AaronBertrand Haha .. google is so small. I just read that. But if you check it, his conclusion was that his version is buggy.

Comment: @DumitrescuBogdan right, but he's not the only person on earth who could write a query that produces the same type of behavior - so it is still something you should be aware of, instead of blindly assuming that GETDATE() always acts as a constant.

Comment: @AaronBertrand agreed, as I stated, in code I do not do it. But on quick sql updates/inserts I rarely bother .. The interesting question is why this happens. Maybe because sql likes to go parallel on some querys, so I guess that each thread will call it's own getdate(). If something makes the threads be slightly offsync they just might get different dates.

Comment: I think parallelism is one case but the UDF example is another where, even single-threaded, the function call would get re-evaluated since you've essentially turned the query into a cursor (and hidden that constant away from SQL Server).

Comment: @AaronBertrand - In this case the OP desires to track changes to rows.  After spending a fair bit of time working on industrial automation systems, I've become rather sensitive to the way in which people (mis)interpret data.  If you cannot distinguish the order in which events occurred then the best course of action is to apply the same date/time to all of them.  Otherwise someone will determine that an earlier event _must_ have caused a later one.

Comment: @HABO in principle I agree, and I even addressed it in my answer, but can you demonstrate a case where this will happen in a simple update in a trigger (where no UDFs are involved)?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

`inserted` is a pseudo-table and it definitely contains all the right rows that were affected by the `UPDATE` statement (and I assume `DISTINCT` isn't necessary, if `ID` a primary key - though it's hard to tell what the table is with a name like `121s`). Whether all of them actually had *changed* values is another thing you may consider validating before applying the modified date/time. Barring that, I would probably do it this way:

```
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[trg_121s] 
ON [dbo].[121s]
AFTER UPDATE
AS 
BEGIN
  SET NOCOUNT ON;

  UPDATE t SET modified = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
   FROM dbo.[121s] AS t
   WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM inserted WHERE ID = t.ID);
   -- WHERE EXISTS is same as INNER JOIN inserted AS i ON t.ID = i.ID;
END
GO
```

If you want to have a 100% foolproof guarantee that they're all updated with the same timestamp (though I don't know if I've ever seen multiple values in this use case):

```
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[trg_121s] 
ON [dbo].[121s]
AFTER UPDATE
AS 
BEGIN
  SET NOCOUNT ON;

  DECLARE @ts DATETIME;
  SET @ts = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP;

  UPDATE t SET modified = @ts
   FROM dbo.[121s] AS t
  INNER JOIN inserted AS i 
  ON t.ID = i.ID;
END
GO
```

And if you want to ensure that the update only occurs if, say, the column `foo` changed value, you could say:

```
  UPDATE t SET modified = @ts
   FROM dbo.[121s] AS t
   INNER JOIN inserted AS i
   ON t.ID = i.ID
   AND t.foo <> i.foo;
```

That's the general pattern, but it becomes more complex if `foo` is nullable, since SQL Server won't be able to match on rows where one side has a value and the other doesn't (or both don't). In that case you would do this:

```
   AND 
   (
     t.foo <> i.foo
     OR (t.foo IS NULL AND i.foo IS NOT NULL)
     OR (t.foo IS NOT NULL AND i.foo IS NULL)
   );
```

Some people will say "I can just use COALESCE or ISNULL against some magic value" like this:

```
WHERE COALESCE(t.foo, 'magic') <> COALESCE(i.foo, 'magic')
```

...and I will warn you against this, because you'll constantly be searching for some magic value that can't exist in the data.

Comment: Thank you - I've marked this as the answer,  as I know from your original comment you must have started working on it straight away.  I really appreciate the other answers too, and have +1d them - so thank you all - the help here is incredible!

Comment: Just a quick query to expand on your answer if you don't mind... I did see another reference to updating the time stamp, only if certain columns (could be more than just one, as in your example) are changed: if update([name]) or update([address]) begin.... is that possible? (for info 121s is a table of one to one meetings with staff, to give an update on performance etc) - thanks again, Mark

Comment: @fixit no, you can't rely on that. If I say `UPDATE foo SET bar = bar` or `bar` is already `1` and I say `UPDATE foo SET bar = 1` then `UPDATE(bar)` will return true, even though I haven't changed the value.

Comment: thank you - so if you did want to have a check on two columns, would you setup two triggers?

Comment: @fixit absolutely not. `AND (t.foo <> i.foo OR t.bar <> i.bar)`

Comment: It's ok for the solution

Comment: is there a reason to use `WHERE EXISTS ...` instead of `JOIN inserted ..`

Comment: @CervEd No, just a personal style preference for me 9 years ago.

Comment: @AaronBertrand I figured it was only stylistic, thanks for verifying

Answer (score 2):

Inserted is a table that contains the rows affected by the operation which fired the trigger(insert/update). So your trigger here is correct. If the Id is primary key, then you do not need the distinct(select id from Inserted is enough). If Id is not primary key, then your trigger is false, as you might end up updating more then you should.

Answer (score 1):

Though many, not just on Stackoverflow, but across the world will tell you triggers are evil, I'm going to say they hold value when they aren't abused. Here, if you wanted to use this trigger, it seems valid and the `Inserted` table contains the rows that were updated by the statement that fired this trigger - it's correct except that `DISTINCT` can probably be removed if `ID` is the primary key.

However, another option if you have the flexibility, is to use a `timestamp` column instead. But, do not be confused, the `timestamp` column **does not** correlate to a date and time. So if you need the date and time, stick with what's there.

Comment: Using timestamp is actually the opposite of what I would suggest. Typically people have to move away from timestamp because what they actually wanted was the date/time, not some unreadable rowversion binary value that doesn't help them track down when a row was modified at all.

Comment: I'm aware of timestamp - I think it's just poorly worded - I know it's being depreciated in the future.