# Trigger that updates another table with only the edited row

Tags: sql, sql-server, database-trigger

Is it possible to create a Trigger on a database that inputs ONLY the row someone edited into a new table. So say in `tbl1` someone changed a column called "name". I would want to take the edited row and place it in `tbl2`. So I would want to take some other columns from `tbl1` of only that edited row and store it in a new table. I want to keep track of when the name was changed and the date and time. Is this even possible with a Trigger? I understand how to set up a table for a trigger event. But am having difficulties understanding how to bring over values from `tbl1` to `tbl2` without having a join.

```
ALTER TRIGGER testname
ON  tbl1
AFTER UPDATE
AS  
IF UPDATE(name)
BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    INSERT INTO tbl2 (ODID,ID2)
    VALUES ();
END
GO
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12462300/trigger-and-update-to-a-row-in-sql-server-after-its-been-updated

Comment: Triggers are **highly vendor-specific** - so please add a tag to specify whether you're using `mysql`, `postgresql`, `sql-server`, `oracle` or `db2` - or something else entirely.

Comment: Sorry about that. It's SQL Server

Comment: Take a look at the [Inserted & Deleted](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/triggers/use-the-inserted-and-deleted-tables?view=sql-server-ver15) pseudo-tables.

Comment: Depending on your version of SQL server, you may find using SQL's native temporal tables does exactly what you're looking for and more. Check it out here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tables/temporal-tables?view=sql-server-ver15

Answer (score 0):

As per your requirement You hv to use dynamic Sql inside trigger.

This is just an idea,

```
ALTER TRIGGER testname
ON  tbl1
AFTER UPDATE
AS 


BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    declare @Sql varchar(500)=''
    declare @Col varchar(500)=''

    IF UPDATE(FirstName)
    set @Col=' FirstName '
    IF UPDATE(LastName)
    set @Col=@Col+', LastName '

    set @Sql='INSERT INTO tbl2 (ODID,ID2)
    select '+@Col+' from inserted'

    sp_executesql @Sql

END
GO
```

This is very cumbersome approach.
Rather create History table which will be replica of tbl1.

```
ALTER TRIGGER testname
ON  tbl1
AFTER UPDATE
AS 


BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    insert into tbl1History
    select * from deleted

END
GO
```